# Laravel: How to get recipient's email address in Laravel mail template for unsubscribe link?

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.6

I need to get the recipient's email address in order to create a unsubscribe link. I want it to work on all emails of my application. So, how can I get the recipient's email address from the vendor mail view of Laravel?

I already tried to call the variables $user, $message, $data and $to inside layout.blade.php and message.blade.php, without success.

Do I need to change some Laravel code (like a controller, or trait) in order to get access to this data?

Comment: Plase provide some code: what variables are sent in the email for instance. Tipically you should sent a unique token and based on that you can identify the user...

Comment: I want to put this link in the email template of Laravel, so it can be used in all emails. So, the recipient's email address it's not meant to be sent as data in a Mail class that I created. I want to get it from the recipient's data received to construct any email. In this case, it's not going to have a token, I just need the email address.